# return <Plug> in a <expr> map

Tags: key-bindings

I know that in `vim`, `map <expr>` allows us to map a key sequence to a new sequence as specified by the return value of an expression. For example:

```
function Wrap()
    if getline('.') == ''
        " can I return a <Plug> here?
        return "Ends an empty line\<cr>"
    else
        return "\<cr>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr> <cr> Wrap()
```

In the expression, `\<cr>` means to return the `<cr>` key.

We can also have `<Plug>` maps like:

```
inoremap <Plug>empty "Ends an empty line\<cr>"
imap <cr> <Plug>empty
```

My question is: if I want to return the `<Plug>empty` map only when cursor is in an empty line like in the first example, what should I do?

---

As @Mass suggested, **the solution is:**

```
inoremap <Plug>empty "Ends an empty line\<cr>"
function Wrap()
    if getline('.') == ''
        return "\<Plug>empty"
    else
        return "\<cr>"
    endif
endfunction
imap <expr> <cr> Wrap()
```

The last line must use `imap` instead of `inoremap`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply `return "\<plug>empty"`  This is doing the same basic thing as `"\<cr>"`, returning a string with special characters instead of literal `<` `c` `r`, `>` etc. Also ensure your `<expr>` map is not using `noremap` so vim uses the `<Plug>` remap. (See the last line in the solution below, using `imap` instead of `inoremap`.)

The solution is:

```
inoremap <Plug>empty "Ends an empty line\<cr>"
function Wrap()
    if getline('.') == ''
        return "\<Plug>empty"
    else
        return "\<cr>"
    endif
endfunction
imap <expr> <cr> Wrap()
```

Comment: thank you very much. I tried this previously and when I type `<cr>`, the literal `\<plug>empty` is obtained and then I come here to seek your help. Now I realized that it is because I have defined the map using `inoremap` instead of `imap`, which prevents the expansion of the `<plug>`. Changing to `imap` solved the problem.